# Errors with Customized ScrollBar Sizing Porting Qt 5.15 QML to Qt 6.0.2 QML

Tags: qt, qml, scrollbar, qt6

I am transitioning a GUI from Qt 5.15 QML to Qt 6.0.2 QML but an error has occurred in `ScrollBar` behavior. I have discovered the issue with MacOS 10.15.7 and I don't know where it exists elsewhere. I create a minimal custom `ScrollBar` and attach it to a `ListView`. The scroll indicator works fine in 5.15 but in 6.x the scroll indicator fills the entire scroll regardless of whether or not it should. Has behavior changed or is this a bug?

I create `CustomScrollbar.qml` as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
ScrollBar {
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 15
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

and then use it in a basic `ListView`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Window {
    width: 300; height: 100; visible: true

    ListView {
        id:listView
        anchors.fill:parent
        ScrollBar.vertical: CustomScrollbar {}

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {name: "Bill"} ListElement {name: "Bob"} ListElement {name: "Andy"} ListElement {name: "Jim"}
            ListElement {name: "Ralph"} ListElement {name: "Ed"} ListElement {name: "Bill"} ListElement {name: "Bill"}
        }
       delegate: Text {
           text: name
       }
    }
}
```

Qt 5.15 produces a properly positioned indicator (left) but Qt 6.0.2 does not scale properly and does not scroll:

[image: BadScrollsBadScrollsWhatchaGonnaDo]

Comment: Setting the matter aside, I'd suggest using properties [`horizontal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#horizontal-prop) and `vertical` in you custom scroll bar component to bind its `implicitWidth` and height conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing the issue appears to be accepted as a verified bug in Qt 6 (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92158)) that has been assigned a `P2 - Important` level. As of several months before this post, [an article by Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Qt-Many-P1-Bugs) notes that there are over 1000 `P1 - Critical` bugs languishing in Qt so it is unclear if the lower level `P2` will see attention soon.

It might be possible to use an external, non-attached scrollbar to workaround this issue but care would need to be taken to not corrupt flickable behavior in the process.